# Как с помощью JS определить по какому именно из блоков был произведён клик?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть следующий фрагмент HTML кода. Если пользователь кликает по одному из блоков внутри блока main, получить по какому именно из блоков с классом "card" был клик. Как это можно сделать с помощью чистого JS?

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="card">
        <a class="green" href="cards.html">
            <img src="assets/img/folder1/1.jpg" alt="img_1">
            <p>img 1</p>
        </a>                    
    </div>              
    <div class="card">
        <a class="green" href="">
            <img src="assets/img/folder2/2.jpg" alt="img_2">
            <p>img 2</p>
        </a>                    
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <a class="green" href="">
            <img src="assets/img/folder3/3.jpg" alt="img_3">
            <p>img 3</p>
        </a>                    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: повесить событие на `body`, а в полученном `event` смотреть `target`

Comment: @Zhihar, точно! Спасибо, сейчас попробую!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('.main').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault()

  var card = e.target.closest('.card')
  card && console.log(card.dataset.id)
})
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="card" data-id="1">
    <a class="green" href="cards.html">
      <img src="assets/img/folder1/1.jpg" alt="img_1">
      <p>img 1</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-id="2">
    <a class="green" href="">
      <img src="assets/img/folder2/2.jpg" alt="img_2">
      <p>img 2</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-id="3">
    <a class="green" href="">
      <img src="assets/img/folder3/3.jpg" alt="img_3">
      <p>img 3</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

При добавлении обработчика события с помощью [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) в качестве `this` внутри обработчика устанавливается элемент, к которому этот обработчик добавлен.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(this.dataset.id)
}));
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="card" data-id="1">
    <a class="green" href="cards.html">
      <img src="assets/img/folder1/1.jpg" alt="img_1">
      <p>img 1</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-id="2">
    <a class="green" href="">
      <img src="assets/img/folder2/2.jpg" alt="img_2">
      <p>img 2</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="card" data-id="3">
    <a class="green" href="">
      <img src="assets/img/folder3/3.jpg" alt="img_3">
      <p>img 3</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Кажется плохой практикой, создание избыточного кол-ва слушателей

Comment: @mego4iter, все зависит от того, как определять избыточность

Comment: наличием более оптимального решения?

Comment: @mego4iter, а как определять оптимальность? :-)

Comment: логически? к примеру 1 слушатель лучше чем 3? =)

Comment: @mego4iter, почему?

Comment: а  зачем, решать задачу списком из 1 элемента если можно решать её списком из 3-х?

Comment: @mego4iter, не понял вопрос :)

Comment: То есть вы предполагаете что решение с 3 подписчиками лучше или эквивалентно решению с одним? (в этом конкретном случае)

Comment: @mego4iter, а ты думаешь, что не эквивалентно? :-)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116810/discussion-between-grundy-and-mego4iter).

Answer (score 0):

Через [`onclick`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onclick) и `event.target`

```
<div class="card" onclick="onClick(event)">
        <a class="green" href="cards.html">
            <img src="assets/img/folder1/1.jpg" alt="img_1">
            <p>img 1</p>
        </a>                    
</div>

function onClick(event) {
  var clickBy = event.target.closest('.card'); // элемент инициировавший вызов (card элкмент)
}
```